# Groups of order 36 have a normal subgroup of order 3 or 9

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to understand the proof from the first two paragraphs from https://math.berkeley.edu/~wodzicki/257/G36.pdf
that groups of order $36$ have a normal subgroup of order $3$ or $9$.

This is what I have so far:

From Sylow's Theorem, we know that the number of Sylow $3$-subgroups is either $1$ or $4$, and that if it is $1$ then we are done, so we can assume that we have $4$ such subroups. Name one of these $P_{9}$.

The left regular group action of G on this subgroup is transitive from a theorem we have, and induces a permutation representation $\Phi: G \rightarrow S_{4}$. From the first Iso theorem, the kernel of this homomorphism, call it $K$, is normal, and $G/K$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_{4}$.

This gives the following conclusions I understand- $\#(G/K)$ divides #($S_{4}$) and $\#(G)$, and can finish the proof if $4$ divides $\#(G/K)$.

What I don't understand is why the action being transitive implies that $36/9=4$ (I assume $\#G/\#P_{9}$) will divide $\#(G/K)$. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: $K$ is a subgroup of $P_9$, so it has order $1$, $3$, or $9$. We can rule out $|K| = 1$ because that would imply that $G$ embeds in $S_4$, which can't happen because $S_4$ is too small. So $|K| = 3$ or $|K| = 9$, and since any kernel is normal, we're done.

Comment: To address the question about transitivity, note this means that there is one orbit under the action. Therefore the orbit-stabilizer theorem gives us $4 = |G/P| = |G/G_P|$ where $G_P$ is the stabilizer of $P$. Since $K$ stabilizes every coset of $P$, we have $K \leq G_P$, hence $4 = |G/G_P|$ divides $|G/K|$ as claimed.